# How to pass a paramater to run method WITHOUT specifying it in contructor

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to pass a parameter to the run method, but all solutions specify to declare the parameters in in the class constructor.

Is there any other way? What if I created an object via a spring bean, I cant instantiate that object again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can set a property on the `Runnable` after construction.

Just make sure that you have proper synchronization, because this property might be changed after the executing thread is started.

```
final class MyTask implements Runnable {
  private volatile int parameter;
  void setParameter(int parameter) { this.parameter = parameter; }
  @Override public void run() { System.out.printf("parameter: %d%n", parameter); }
}
```